# n-th or Arbitrary Combination of a Large Set

Tags: c++, algorithm, permutation, combinations

Say I have a set of numbers from `[0, ....., 499]`. Combinations are currently being generated sequentially using the C++ `std::next_permutation`. For reference, the size of each tuple I am pulling out is 3, so I am returning sequential results such as `[0,1,2], [0,1,3], [0,1,4], ... [497,498,499]`.

Now, I want to parallelize the code that this is sitting in, so a sequential generation of these combinations will no longer work. Are there any existing algorithms for computing the `ith` combination of 3 from 500 numbers?

I want to make sure that each thread, regardless of the iterations of the loop it gets, can compute a standalone combination based on the `i` it is iterating with. So if I want the combination for `i=38` in thread 1, I can compute `[1,2,5]` while simultaneously computing `i=0` in thread 2 as `[0,1,2]`.

**EDIT** Below statement is irrelevant, I mixed myself up

I've looked at algorithms that utilize factorials to narrow down each individual element from left to right, but I can't use these as 500! sure won't fit into memory. Any suggestions?

Comment: Show us the calculations involving factorial.  You might just be looking at it wrong.  Surely you will be dividing one factorial into another, which generally means a simplification is possible.

Comment: I think I need to rephrase my question. It's not just a permutation of 500 numbers. It's a combination of 3 out of 500 possible. But I want to be able to select an arbitrary combination out of the 500 choose 3 possible.

Comment: Perhaps something like the following:   http://code.google.com/p/strtk/source/browse/trunk/strtk.hpp#11622

Comment: @Gerdiner if I could accept an answer from you I would. That code is more general and works exactly as needed as well. Great algorithm there. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is my shot:

```
int k = 527; //The kth combination is calculated
int N=500; //Number of Elements you have
int a=0,b=1,c=2; //a,b,c are the numbers you get out

while(k >= (N-a-1)*(N-a-2)/2){
    k -= (N-a-1)*(N-a-2)/2;
    a++;
}
b= a+1;
while(k >= N-1-b){
    k -= N-1-b;
    b++;
}

c = b+1+k;


cout << "["<<a<<","<<b<<","<<c<<"]"<<endl; //The result
```

Got this thinking about how many combinations there are until the next number is increased. However it only works for three elements. I can't guarantee that it is correct. Would be cool if you compare it to your results and give some feedback.

Comment: Simple, quick, works as far as I can tell. I was trying to come up with something similar to what jacobm had written, but I do like this!

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a way to obtain the lexicographic index or rank of a unique combination instead of a permutation, then your problem falls under the binomial coefficient.  The binomial coefficient handles problems of choosing unique combinations in groups of K with a total of N items.

I have written a class in C# to handle common functions for working with the binomial coefficient.  It performs the following tasks:

1. Outputs all the K-indexes in a nice format for any N choose K to a file.  The K-indexes can be substituted with more descriptive strings or letters.
2. Converts the K-indexes to the proper lexicographic index or rank of an entry in the sorted binomial coefficient table.  This technique is much faster than older published techniques that rely on iteration.  It does this by using a mathematical property inherent in Pascal's Triangle and is very efficient compared to iterating over the set.
3. Converts the index in a sorted binomial coefficient table to the corresponding K-indexes.  I believe it is also faster than older iterative solutions.
4. Uses [Mark Dominus](http://blog.plover.com/math/choose.html) method to calculate the binomial coefficient, which is much less likely to overflow and works with larger numbers.
5. The class is written in .NET C# and provides a way to manage the objects related to the problem (if any) by using a generic list.  The constructor of this class takes a bool value called InitTable that when true will create a generic list to hold the objects to be managed.  If this value is false, then it will not create the table.  The table does not need to be created in order to use the 4 above methods.  Accessor methods are provided to access the table.
6. There is an associated test class which shows how to use the class and its methods.  It has been extensively tested with 2 cases and there are no known bugs.

To read about this class and download the code, see [Tablizing The Binomial Coeffieicent](http://tablizingthebinomialcoeff.wordpress.com/).

The following tested code will iterate through each unique combinations:

```
public void Test10Choose5()
{
   String S;
   int Loop;
   int N = 500;  // Total number of elements in the set.
   int K = 3;  // Total number of elements in each group.
   // Create the bin coeff object required to get all
   // the combos for this N choose K combination.
   BinCoeff<int> BC = new BinCoeff<int>(N, K, false);
   int NumCombos = BinCoeff<int>.GetBinCoeff(N, K);
   // The Kindexes array specifies the indexes for a lexigraphic element.
   int[] KIndexes = new int[K];
   StringBuilder SB = new StringBuilder();
   // Loop thru all the combinations for this N choose K case.
   for (int Combo = 0; Combo < NumCombos; Combo++)
   {
      // Get the k-indexes for this combination.  
      BC.GetKIndexes(Combo, KIndexes);
      // Verify that the Kindexes returned can be used to retrive the
      // rank or lexigraphic order of the KIndexes in the table.
      int Val = BC.GetIndex(true, KIndexes);
      if (Val != Combo)
      {
         S = "Val of " + Val.ToString() + " != Combo Value of " + Combo.ToString();
         Console.WriteLine(S);
      }
      SB.Remove(0, SB.Length);
      for (Loop = 0; Loop < K; Loop++)
      {
         SB.Append(KIndexes[Loop].ToString());
         if (Loop < K - 1)
            SB.Append(" ");
      }
      S = "KIndexes = " + SB.ToString();
      Console.WriteLine(S);
   }
}
```

You should be able to port this class over fairly easily to C++.  You probably will not have to port over the generic part of the class to accomplish your goals.  Your test case of 500 choose 3 yields 20,708,500 unique combinations, which will fit in a 4 byte int.  If 500 choose 3 is simply an example case and you need to choose combinations greater than 3, then you will have to use longs or perhaps fixed point int.

Comment: I will definitely look into this. 500 choose 3 is guaranteed to be a worst case for the parameters we are looking at, so I am not too worried about overflows.

Comment: I ported your code @Bob Bryan to Java.
You can find it in https://github.com/aalhossary/BinomialCoefficient

Answer (score 0):

You can describe a particular selection of 3 out of 500 objects as a triple `(i, j, k)`, where `i` is a number from 0 to 499 (the index of the first number), `j` ranges from 0 to 498 (the index of the second, skipping over whichever number was first), and `k` ranges from 0 to 497 (index of the last, skipping both previously-selected numbers). Given that, it's actually pretty easy to enumerate all the possible selections: starting with `(0,0,0)`, increment `k` until it gets to its maximum value, then increment `j` and reset `k` to 0 and so on, until `j` gets to its maximum value, and so on, until `j` gets to its own maximum value; then increment `i` and reset both `j` and `k` and continue.

If this description sounds familiar, it's because it's exactly the same way that incrementing a base-10 number works, except that the base is much funkier, and in fact the base *varies* from digit to digit. You can use this insight to implement a very compact version of the idea: for any integer `n` from 0 to 500*499*498, you can get:

```
struct {
  int i, j, k;
} triple;

triple AsTriple(int n) {
  triple result;
  result.k = n % 498;
  n = n / 498;
  result.j = n % 499;
  n = n / 499;
  result.i = n % 500;  // unnecessary, any legal n will already be between 0 and 499
  return result;
}

void PrintSelections(triple t) {
  int i, j, k;
  i = t.i;
  j = t.j + (i <= j ? 1 : 0);
  k = t.k + (i <= k ? 1 : 0) + (j <= k ? 1 : 0);
  std::cout << "[" << i << "," << j << "," << k << "]" << std::endl;
}

void PrintRange(int start, int end) {
  for (int i = start; i < end; ++i) {
    PrintSelections(AsTriple(i));
  }
}
```

Now to shard, you can just take the numbers from 0 to 500*499*498, divide them into subranges in any way you'd like, and have each shard compute the permutation for each value in its subrange.

This trick is very handy for any problem in which you need to enumerate subsets.

Comment: The only issue here is that I'd end up with duplication. I need 500 choose 3 combinations (worst case), which is ~20 million combinations. This occurs with no duplication, so (0,0,0) is eliminated. Thank you though, I appreciate the answer!

Comment: No, there's no duplication the way I described it. The trick is in the interpretation: (0,0,0) represents the first, second, and third elements, since for each number you skip all the elements you've already picked.

Comment: Ahhhh. I see now. I'll test it out a bit!

Comment: FYI, updated the code sample above to be more complete and hopefully clarify the way that the numbers get interpreted a bit.

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  You can trivially see that by invoking PrintRange(0, 1).  It prints [0,1,1], which isn't even a valid combination.  It also produces lots of duplicates.  For example, it maps 1 to [0,1,2] and 498 to [0,2,1].  Solving this correctly requires a more complicated calculation.

Comment: I just tried `PrintRange(0,1)` on my machine and it prints `[0,1,2]` as expected; are you sure you copied the code correctly? About the duplicates though: From the description I thought the original poster was looking for all _permutations_ (i.e. all of the distinct sequences of 3 different numbers from 1-500) which this code does. If it's all _subsets_ of size 3 instead then yes, this algorithm won't work.